# Why is my Android phone more stable than my Windows desktop?

Tags: android, windows, stability

My Android phone has never crashed as far as I know in the two years I have had it.

My Windows desktop crashes at last once a month.

Why is the Android phone more stable than the Windows desktop?

Comment: This belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: These things aren't comparable. And yes windows has issues but it's still a useful operating system and linux (which is what android is written in) also has it's fair share of problems although maybe not as much. But you really can't compare your phone to a full sized desktop as there's a lot more going on in your desktop than on your phone.

Comment: I find it amazing that Windows is as stable as it is considering that a whole lot of the Windows device drivers out there written by third parties are borderline crap (e.g. nVidia, ATI) whereas you don't typically install new hardware/device drivers on a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons for this. First off the complexity of windows is a lot higher than android, there are millions of lines of code and as every programmer does some mistakes sometimes crashes are more likely to occur.

The second reason is probably that windows is highly customizeable, almost everyone is using third party programs that interact with windows, changing your settings and also making the system unstable (especially if installing drivers).

If you set up a clean patched version of Windows and don't install any programs that harm the system stability it will also not crash.